# Twitter share button "frame was blocked"

Tags: twitter, https, frame

After adding the Twitter share button from here:

http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton

My https site displays a small rectangular box appears on my pages with this error:

> This frame was blocked because it
>   contains some insecure content.

When I change the two http calls to https:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share"...
...src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js">
```

I get a text "Tweet" link, which does work, but it doesn't have the images/layout from the Twitter site. The javascript call outputs this error in the code:

```
Failed to load source for: https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js
```

Is there anything I can do to get this Twitter button working?

Comment: Twitter recently enabled HTTPS, but I don't know if it covers that URL. Unfortunately it's blocked at my work so I can't test, but have you tried just using https:// instead of http:// for the link?

Comment: I just updated my answer trying https. Unfortunately it's still not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter currently [doesn't offer the Tweet button via HTTPS](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_button_faq#https) so your only option at this stage is to [roll your own](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_button#build-your-own).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Too bad that's the only option - that'll take way too long. Guess I'll go with tweetmeme instead.

Answer (score 1):

At this time tweetmeme does not seem to be secure either.

The only way to do this is securely to use a query string, e.g.

```
<A HREF=https://twitter.com/share?url=MYURL&via=VIA&text=TWEET>Tweet</A>
```

But there is no way to get the tweet count yet, and you have to dispose of the tweet window yourself.